# Json parsing in flutter application taking too much time

Tags: json, flutter

I have a json file with 40,000 entries approx. I am trying to parse it in my flutter application. i am getting the json and converting it successfully in desired model. But the problem is, it is taking too much time to load. My json file is stored in Firebase storage bucket. Is there any other way so that it could load quickly ? I was thinking of storing the data in realtime database, but i am sure that there also it will quickly give the results or not. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

```
class CollegeCode {
  final String college_code;
  final String studentcode;
  final String college_Name;
  final String college_Location;

  CollegeCode({this.college_code, this.college_Name, this.college_Location, this.studentcode});

  factory CollegeCode.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
     CollegeCode(
      college_code: json['College Code'] ,
      college_Location: json['Location'],
      college_Name: json['College Name'],
      studentcode: json['Student Code']
    );

}
class GetList{
  GetList({this.data});
  List<CollegeCode> data;

  factory GetList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // print(json['CollegesList'].toString());
    if(json != null){

      return GetList(

        data: List<CollegeCode>.from(

            json["CollegesList"].map((x) => CollegeCode.fromJson(x))).toList() ?? [],
      );
    }
    return GetList(data: []);

  }
}

Future <List<CollegeCode>> parsePhotos(String responseBody) async{

    if(responseBody.isNotEmpty) {
      final parsed = await GetList.fromJson(json.decode(responseBody));

      final datalist = parsed.data.toList();
      return datalist;
    }

}



Future<List<CollegeCode>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
  await client.get(url of file in storage bucket');

  // print(response.body);
  return parsePhotos(response.body);
  // return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}
```

I want to know if there is any alternate of doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect to have 40 000 entries getting processed in an instant. If you desire to use a local database, the [sqflite package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) is great for that purpose, as it even provides batches, where large amounts of information can be processed in shorter times, albeit costing memory.

Furthermore, you might want to check if the amount of information that you are processing falls under [these parameters](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)

Comment: i am not familiar with sqflite package. i will definitely check it out. I want to know if there is  any substitute of this. so that i don't have to parse this amount of entries at once.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the decoding which takes time vs transferring this giant file over the wire?

Comment: I am not sure about it. I am using the future builder to access the data. I have added the snippet , the way i am trying to do so.

Comment: There are no red flags in your snippet. So, what I would do it print timing info there so see exactly which part is taking more part. Something like this: `final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start(); <...expansive operation...>; print('done in ${stopwatch.elapsed}');`. So at least you can figure out if it's the server roundtrip or the json parsing that's killing you.